# User List and Ip List for Monitoring in SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I got questions regarding Monitoring in Softlayer.
How can I get IP Address List to add ? There are more IPs than primary ips. Is there API to get IPs for monitoring?

How can i get User List to notify ? The code I used brings no user.

```
    List<Agent> agentList = guest.getMonitoringAgents();

    for (Agent agent : agentList) {

        List<Customer> custList = agent.asService(client).getEligibleAlarmSubscibers();
```

}

[image: Ip List]
[image: User List]

Comment: Mike, my apologies for the information that I provided before, currently it's possible to get ip addresses and user list to notify, see the updates in my answer. Let me know if you need more assistance with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get Ip Address list to add, you can try the following methods:**

- For Virtual Guest:

  - [SoftLayer_Network_Monitor::getIpAddressesByVirtualGuest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor/getIpAddressesByVirtualGuest)
- For Hardware:

  - [SoftLayer_Network_Monitor::getIpAddressesByHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor/getIpAddressesByHardware)

> [**Updated**] Here an example to get ip addresses by hardware

```
package com.softlayer.api.NetworkMonitor;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Monitor;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.subnet.IpAddress;

/**
 * This script will return an arrayObject of objects containing the ipaddresses for hardware
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Monitor/getIpAddressesByHardware
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetIpAddressesByHardware {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Get Ip Addresses By Hardware
     */
    public GetIpAddressesByHardware() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Hardware identifier
        Long hardwareId = new Long(92862);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

       Monitor.Service monitorService = Monitor.service(client);

        Hardware hardware = new Hardware();
        hardware.setId(hardwareId);
        try {
            for(IpAddress ipAddress : monitorService.getIpAddressesByHardware(hardware, ""))
            {
                System.out.println("Ip Address: " + ipAddress.getIpAddress());
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetIpAddressesByHardware method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetIpAddressesByHardware();
    }


}
```

**Regarding to: How can i get User List to notify ?**

The following methods will help with that:

- For Hardware:

  - [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getUsers)
- For Virtual Guest:

  - [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUsers)

> [**Updated**] Here an script using [SoftLayer_Hardware_Server::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getUsers)

```
package com.softlayer.api.HardwareServer;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.hardware.Server;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.Customer;

/**
 * This script retrieves a list of users that have access to this computing instance.
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getUsers
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_User_Customer
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetUsers {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Get Users from hardware
     */
    public GetUsers() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define Hardware identifier
        Long hardwareId = new Long(92862);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        Server.Service serverService = Server.service(client, hardwareId);
        try {
            for(Customer user : serverService.getUsers())
            {
                System.out.println("Id: " + user.getId());
                System.out.println("User: " + user.getLastName() + ", " + user.getFirstName() + "(" + user.getUsername() + ")");
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetUsers method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetUsers();
    }


}
```

Here an script using [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUsers):

```
package Monitoring;

import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.Customer;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;

/**
 * This script retrieve a list of users that have access to this computing instance.
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUsers
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_User_Customer
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetUserList {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to Add users to notify
     */
    public GetUserList() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Define the virtual guest id
        Long guestId = new Long(18697221);

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);

        // Define SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest service
        Guest.Service guestService = Guest.service(client, guestId);


        try {
            for(Customer user : guestService.getUsers())
            {
                System.out.println("Id: " + user.getId());
                System.out.println("User: " + user.getLastName() + ", " + user.getFirstName() + "(" + user.getUsername() + ")");
                System.out.println("----------------------------");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetUserList method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetUserList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw your updated code, but "com.softlayer.api.service.network.Monitor" class is not my java library. My java lib version is 0.2.2. Where can I get the Monitor class ?

Comment: Yep, I had the same mistake, but you should try the latest master branch and compile the sources via maven again. https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues/33

Comment: In the current master version, there is no "com.softlayer.api.service" package. Could you link me where you get ? Thanks

Comment: Please, Try these steps:

1. Pull or download master branch from https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java, 2. Compile the project with maven,  3. Open the project compiled and try the examples that I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry bothering you.. The zip file you downloaded is softlayer-java-master.zip(91kb). right? Monitor class is supposed to be there. right ? But I can't find it..

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad to help you. After you download the **softlayer-java-master.zip(91kb)**, you should unzip it. after that, open a Command Prompt (I suppose that you are using Windows), go to the path that you unzipped the project, and compile the project using maven **mvn compile**, after that, open the project and try to use the scripts that I provided, they should work fine.

Comment: Let me know, if you have success or any question, in order that I can help you.